# Expanding a HTML Spreadsheet

Tags: html, web, spreadsheet

I have a google spreadsheet embedded onto a website with

`<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/SPREADSHEETURL&amp;single=true&amp;widget=true&amp;headers=false" style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>`

But I want the table to be expanded vertically be default. You can only see the lower part of the spreadsheet by scrolling, but I want it to be default to show the whole spreadsheet.

### BONUS:

I also want to be able to remove the part at the top of the spreadsheet that says the spreadsheet name.

Thanks in advance.

### EDIT:

I may have found what I was looking for here

`<iframe width="100%" height="160" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/SPREADSHEETURL&amp;single=true&amp;widget=false&amp;chrome=false" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>`

Which works partially, but the scrolling problem is still there. Scrolling is the only way to see the lower portion of the spreadsheet. Also, it takes a long time to update on the website, but that may be Google's problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it out, I must've been overthinking it.

`<iframe width="100%" height="1600" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/SPREADSHEETURL&amp;single=true&amp;widget=false&amp;chrome=false" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>`

I just changed the height parameter to whatever I need.

[This site](https://wp-glogin.com/2014/08/embedding-google-spreadsheets-with-more-control-over-appearance/) helped me out a lot.